# private variable mean in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, scope, closures, private

What is mean 'private variable' in javascript?
There isn`t 'private variable' declare in javascript.

so we usually have used '_' or closure.

In this Point, I was curious 'closure'.
I got example from another site.

```
function createAnimal(name, job) {
  // "Private" variables here
  let _name = name;
  let _job = job;

  // Public variables here
  return {
    // Getter Methods
    getName() {
      return _name;
    },
    getJob() {
      return _job;
    },
    // Setter Methods
    setName(newName) {
      _name = newName;
    },
    setJob(newJob) {
      _job = newJob;
    }
  };
}
```

Above example
we can change _name 'private variable' of setName.
***Reault***
'private variable' mean that we can`t access variable? or constant?

Comment: `_` is just a convention.  @info2ankit's answer is pretty spot on.

Comment: There is a currently a [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#private-fields) for [private fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields)

Answer (score 1):

I hope, this may help you:

> Private members are made by the constructor. Ordinary vars and
>   parameters of the constructor become the private members.

```
function Container(param) {
    this.member = param;
    var secret = 3;
    var that = this;
}
```

> This constructor makes three private instance variables: param,
>   secret, and that. They are attached to the object, but they are not
>   accessible to the outside, nor are they accessible to the object's own
>   public methods. They are accessible to private methods. Private
>   methods are inner functions of the constructor.

```
function Container(param) {

    function dec() {
        if (secret > 0) {
            secret -= 1;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    this.member = param;
    var secret = 3;
    var that = this;
}
```

> The private method dec examines the secret instance variable. If it is
>   greater than zero, it decrements secret and returns true. Otherwise it
>   returns false. It can be used to make this object limited to three
>   uses.
>
> By convention, we make a private that variable. This is used to make
>   the object available to the private methods. This is a workaround for
>   an error in the ECMAScript Language Specification which causes this to
>   be set incorrectly for inner functions.
>
> Private methods cannot be called by public methods. To make private
>   methods useful, we need to introduce a privileged method.

Reference: [Read more](https://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html)

Comment: Thank you. I read your comment. And I thought In and of itself 'private variable' is not constant.

Comment: @JangSeonHo yes you are right, it's not mandatory that private variable must be a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Private variables are hidden, and therefore can't be accessed *directly*. For instance, you would **not** be able to call `animal._name = "Rover"`.

Instead, you're expected to call a function that *encapsulates* the variable. In your example, you would instead call `animal.setName("Rover")`. So, these variables aren't necessarily constant, but they can only be changed by calling special methods that change them internally.

Programmers like private variables sometimes, because there are situations where manipulating a variable directly could cause issues.

For instance:

```js
function createLogger() {
  let _numMessagesLogged = 0;

  return {
    logMessage(message) {
      console.log(message);
      _numMessagesLogged += 1;
    },
    getNumMessagesLogged() {
      return _numMessagesLogged;
    },
  };
}
```

In this example, we increment a counter (`_numMessagesLogged`) every time a message is logged. If the counter were public, someone could set `logger._numMessagesLogged = -12345`, which doesn't make any sense. Instead, we want the variable to be private, so that we know for sure that the number of messages logged increases **only** when we log something-- that is, it increases **only** when we call `logMessage()`.

Closures are just one way of implementing private members via JavaScript. There are other ways to do this as well, but the method isn't as important as the underlying concept.

You may be interested in [reading more about encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).